# EF 4.1 SeedData not populating table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have created a SeedData class, and populated it with the values that I would like to be populated into the table. When I run the application, I am not getting any errors, but the table is not populating with the Seed Data.

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and EF 4.1

I have tried both DropCreateDatabaseAlways and DropCreateIfModelChanges with no luck

In the Global ASAX I have the following link in Application_Start

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new EDWv2.Models.SeedData());
```

My SeedData class is define as follows:

```
public class SeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EDWContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EDWContext context)
    {

        var controlsystemdesignation = new List<ControlSystemDesignation>
        {
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "BA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "BP"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "RA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "GA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "WA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "WB"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "WC"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "EA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "EB"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "EC"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "DA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "DB"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "DC"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "FA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "FB"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "SA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "SB"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "SC"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "LA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "LD"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "DP"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "PA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "PB"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "PC"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "UL"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "UA"}
    };
        base.Seed(context);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ControlSystemDesignation` entities to `context`.

```
public class SeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EDWContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EDWContext context)
    {

        var controlsystemdesignation = new List<ControlSystemDesignation>
        {
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "BA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "BP"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "RA"},
            new ControlSystemDesignation { Name = "GA"}
            //...
        };

        controlsystemdesignation.ForEach(item => context.ControlSystemDesignations.Add(item));

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the tip, it helped me to get the data populated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add those instances to a `DbSet<ControlSystemDesignation>`, which should be part of your context.

```
context.ControlSystemDesignations.Add(instance);
```